# Numpy-recarray, C# structured data

Tags: python, c#, numpy

I have written a consumer of data in C# that reads string data from python API script.  The best performing method I have found so far is to get the data into a `numpy-recarray` in python, print it to the console and read it with StreamReader.

I end up with the following string in the reading C# routine.  This is one long string (7,000 records) of stock quotes, (Date, Open, High, Low, Close). No carriage returns, no line feeds.

[(datetime.date(2020, 6, 1), 29.80, 30.65, 29.45, 30.24), (datetime.date(2020, 6, 2), 30.49, 31.43, 30.19, 31.17)...]

I now need to parse this somehow into something that I can easily use to insert this data into a SQL database.  I know how to do the insert from a list, array, etc.  I can see a brut force parsing routing that reads this character by character and rebuilds the records into a List. Then the SQL bulk insert is easy.

I feel like there might be a better approach to alter the python console writer to write this long string in a format that could be converted to a List in C# with Linq or some other assignment.  I am a little confused on where to start.  Any suggestions?

Comment: If the data generated by python is going to be parsed only by your c# code then it is good to change python code to produce DateTime data in some generic format so that parsing in C# becomes easy.

Comment: With 7000 records you might also have missing data, replace by ellipsis (...).  As a general rule, `numpy` array `print` is not intended for parsing, that is, for recreating an array.   The `print` of a `arr.tolist()` is better, but it too will be a list of tuples.  A pretty printer might break it up into lines.

Comment: I could do something like this.  List<Bar> bars = new List<Bar>();
   bars.Add(new Bar() { Date = "2009-01-01", Open = "30.20", Close = "29.25"....}*{}*{}...  Where the string starting with { ending with }* is formatted in python before sent to C#.  Then a string split on * gives us the records to loop through.  I am going to loop through 30 million or so bars, so I am researching this for performance concerns.
 })

Comment: Thank you hpaulj, I am using arr.tolist() and the result described above is what I get.  I do seem to get all of the data.

Comment: What format would be easy to work with?  How about the date field?

Answer (score 0):

You might be happier with a `pandas` produced `csv`:

Just to crudely take you list of tuples:

```
In [25]: alist = [(datetime.date(2020, 6, 1), 29.80, 30.65, 29.45, 30.24), (date
    ...: time.date(2020, 6, 2), 30.49, 31.43, 30.19, 31.17)]                    
In [26]: alist                                                                  
Out[26]: 
[(datetime.date(2020, 6, 1), 29.8, 30.65, 29.45, 30.24),
 (datetime.date(2020, 6, 2), 30.49, 31.43, 30.19, 31.17)]

In [28]: import pandas as pd                                                    
In [29]: df=pd.DataFrame(alist)                                                 
In [30]: df                                                                     
Out[30]: 
            0      1      2      3      4
0  2020-06-01  29.80  30.65  29.45  30.24
1  2020-06-02  30.49  31.43  30.19  31.17
In [31]: df.to_csv('test.csv')                                                  
In [32]: cat test.csv                                                           
,0,1,2,3,4
0,2020-06-01,29.8,30.65,29.45,30.24
1,2020-06-02,30.49,31.43,30.19,31.17
```

You can refine that output with or without the column headers and row indices.

There is also a `numpy` `savetxt` that could be more work to use with a structured array like this.

Comment: Good thoughts.  I will do some testing.  I have the "format a long string in python from numpy so C# can consume into a list of objects" method figured out.  The API can also provide the raw data to me as pandas dataframe. The question is what is the fastest way to transfer the data through the console. So far writing one big string is much faster than writing 7,000 lines. Now that doesn't consider parsing on the other end.  More testing.  I'll report back unless someone knows more.